# Python write file as UTF-8 instead of ANSI

Tags: python

I have run below piece of python code to write a new file replacing a string from the i/p file. It is working fine. But o/p file is getting created with ANSI encoding, whereas input file is utf-8 w/o BOM. Can some one please guide me how to create o/p file with same attribute as i/p file?

Thanks in advance.

```
import codecs

f1=open(r"D:\Python Programs\New folder\ls.dat","rb")
f2=open(r"D:\Python Programs\New folder\OUTPUT.DAT","wb")

for line in f1:
    s1=line[0:len(line)]
    s3=s1[72:76].replace(str.encode("HKAG"),str.encode("PNAG"))
    s4=s1[0:72]+s3+s1[76:]
    f2.write(s4)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the encoding `open` from the `io` package instead of trying to roll your own.

```
import io
from __future__ import unicode_literals

with io.open(r"D:\Python Programs\New folder\ls.dat", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f1:
  with io.open(r"D:\Python Programs\New folder\OUTPUT.DAT", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f2:
    for line in f1:
      s1=line[0:len(line)]
      s3=s1[72:76].replace(u"HKAG", u"PNAG")
      s4=s1[0:72]+s3+s1[76:]
      f2.write(s4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I made changes as per our suggestion.Now it throws error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 3126: invalid start byte". Can you please tell me what should be correct write statement. Below is the modified write statement.

f2.write(s4.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: @PinakiNag You don't need to call encode or decode explicitly. I've edited the code to show how you can leave it all to the io.open function to worry about encoding; then you just read and write unicode strings.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Programs\New folder\py3.py", line 6, in <module>
    for line in f1:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 3126: invalid start byte

Is there any problem with the i/p file?

Comment: Sounds like it's not valid UTF-8 after all. A 0xff byte is not allowed anywhere in a well-formed UTF-8 stream.